# Time varying gain simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a block diagram in Simulink where one of the blocks is `gain` and depends on time.

How can I set the gain to change according to the simulation time?

I tried to use `clock` block, send the variable `to workspace` and then set it back to gain parameter however its not working.

```
mdl_name='HW3_Q1_Sim';
open_system(mdl_name);
a = sim('HW3_Q1_Sim','SimulationMode','normal');
SimTime = a.get('SimTime');
x = SimTime^2;
set_param([mdl_name,'/Gain1'],'Gain',x);
```

Any tips please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following blocks:

- [Math function block](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/mathfunction.html) (set to "square")
- [Clock block](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/clock.html)
- [Product block](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/product.html)

Arranged in that manner:

[image]

Comment: Why is it working in the first place? You take quadratic value of the clock and multiply it with signal? What is that?